# Quelles seraient d'autres façons de dire: « Le seul but de la bureaucratie serait d'assurer sa pérennité et de s'accroître toujours plus. » ?

Tags: sens, formulation, reformulation

Doit-on comprendre, selon la phrase, la bureaucratie comme une forme de régime qui s'autonomise, qui s'autosuffit et dont l'existence se justifie par la création d'emplois?

Contexte de la phrase:

> Pour le grand public, "bureaucratie" est souvent synonyme d'inefficacité, de paresse, de dépenses inutiles, d'effectifs pléthoriques, de privilèges. Le seul but de la bureaucratie serait d'assurer sa pérennité et de s'accroître toujours plus, au détriment des "vrais travailleurs". Ce type d'argumentaires est fréquemment utilisé par les partis populistes et les syndicats patronaux.

Comment: Définition capitaliste qui oblitère les services non monétisables rendus.

Comment: @GermaineLeBrun la phrase du titre est parfaite et sans ambiguïté. Je ne comprends pas bien si vous posez une question de reformulation ou de compréhension ? Quel est le contexte et pourquoi "devrait-on comprendre" autre chose que ce que la phrase dit ?

Comment: Je pose une question de reformulation mais comme je ne suis pas certaine du sens à donner à l’idée, j’ai tenté de la développer en fonction de l’interprétation que je m’en suis fait et au risque d’extrapoler…

Comment: @guillaume31 Si le but de la bureaucratie est d’assurer sa pérennité et sa croissance, j’infère que…

Comment: @guillaume31 J’ai ajouté le contexte dans le corps de la question.

Comment: Pourquoi vouloir assurer sa survie et sa croissance?

Comment: Correction: «[…] l’interprétation que je m’en suis fait-e- ✔️

Comment: La signifcation du texte est assez claire. Quel est le point/terme qui pose question dans la reformulation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C'est tellement philosophique que je crois qu'on va avoir des ennuis pour justifier l'existence de cette question sur le SFE, et qu'on n'ira pas bien loin dans la clarification de ce qui n'est pas une simple question mais un sujet ; le corps de la question diverge abruptement du but annoncé dans le titre.

Ce qu'on doit comprendre c'est, je crois, ce que  nous disent les dessins caricaturistes  qui représentent la bureaucratie comme une pieuvre, bien que ces dessins par eux-mêmes ne suffisent pas et ne sont qu'un squelette. Je vais donc m'en tenir au titre, qui d'ailleurs, pris sans une légère modification, est une énormité : le seul but n'est pas son expansion ; il  peut-être au plus un de ses buts.

- La bureaucratie est un phénomène qui engendre sa propre prolifération.

Answer (score 0):

> Doit-on comprendre, selon la phrase, la bureaucratie comme une forme de régime qui s'autonomise

Oui

> qui s'autosuffit et dont l'existence se justifie par la création d'emplois?

Pas exactement, la création d'emplois ayant une connotation positive. Ici, on parle d'effectifs pléthoriques (plutôt péjoratif) et ce n'est pas presenté comme une justification mais un effet pervers. Il y a personification de la bureaucratie qui est comparée a un parasite grandissant qui s'abreuve sur le dos de l'économie "réelle".